# Music player with searchable library, that supports multiple artists?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I have a local library of many mp3 songs.

I want a music player that fully supports multiple artists in a song. For example, in a list of all artists in my library, if a song has as artists:

`Michael Jackson/Usher`

The list of Artists should realize that these are two separate artists on the same song, so it should not display an artist with the name `Michael Jackson/Usher`. Instead, the same song should appear under both artists.

The same goes for multiple genres.

I hate to say it, but Windows Media Player got this right (although they separate artists with `;` instead of `/`, but that's not the main point here).

What music players are available that have this feature? Ideally, it should be as light weight as possible. I am not interested in support of streaming/radio/online services. I just want to manage my local mp3 collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gmusicbrowser** supports multiple artists in a song and displays the same song when one of the artists is being selected at a time.

### How it works

There are two conditions to get this work correctly:

1. music player that supports filtering by artist (the application is also sometimes known as "music jukebox" or "jukebox")
2. song metadata that contains multiple artists, which need to be separated by a semicolon '`;`' between two artists (or other supported separators)

To describe condition #2, I happened to have just one song with multiple artists i.e. `L.Storch, oboe; M. Friedmann, violin` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Song metadata with a semicolon]

### Semicolon or slash

Besides a semicolon, you can also use a slash '`/`', which may be preceded and followed by spaces i.e. `L.Storch, oboe / M. Friedmann, violin`. This works fine in gmusicbrowser, but untested with other music players.

[image: Song metadata with a slash]

An ampersand '`&`' will *not* work. A comma '`,`' oddly works similar to a slash, which may be spaced at both sides. Anyway, the song in my list was using a semicolon by default.

### Filtering in action

In the following GIF animated image, I am using gmusicbrowser with "Shimmer Desktop" layout in "Simple List View". I selected the corresponding genre, then selected one artist at a time.

[image: gmusicbrowser filter artists]

Tested working with gmusicbrowser 1.1.12 in Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-valued tags is built in to all parts of [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

To create multiple values, you can add them yourself, read ones already in any supported format, or split existing ones using a range of pre- or custom- defined splitters (`/`, `&`, `-`, `and`...).

[image]

Then querying by any tag is possible, as are metatags like `~people` (which scans `artist`, `albumartist`, `performer`, `conductor`, `composer` etc).